# Hackerrank Sum vs XoR

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, bitwise

I'm in the process of improving my coding style and performance hence I decided to delve into bit manipulation on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sum-vs-xor/copy-from/31845766). I thought the question was straight forward but on large input, my solution's performance declines. How do I improve it? Any smart tricks to solve the below question is welcome as well.

Below is the question

> Given an integer, *\$n\$* , find each *\$x\$* such that:
>
> \$0 \leq x \leq n \$
>
> \$ n + x = n \oplus x \$
>
> where \$\oplus\$ denotes the bitwise XOR operator. Then print an
>   integer denoting the total number of \$x\$ 's satisfying the criteria
>   above.
>
> ### **Input Format**
>
> A single integer, \$n\$ .
>
> ### Constraints
>
> \$0 \leq n \leq 10 ^ {15}\$
>
> ### Subtasks
>
> \$0 \leq n \leq 100\$ for \$60\%\$ of the maximum score
>
> ### Output Format
>
> Print the total number of integer \$x\$ 's satisfying both of the
>   conditions specified above.
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> ```
> 5
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 0**
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> **Explanation 0**
>
> For \$n = 5\$ , the \$x\$ values \$0\$  and \$2\$ satisfy the
>   conditions:
>
> Thus, we print \$2\$ as our answer.

---

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution {
     static int SumVsXoR(long number)
    {
        int count =0;
        long j = 0;
        while (j <= number)
        {           
            if(j + number == (j^number)){               
                count++;                
            }
            j++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    static void Main(String[] args) {
        long n = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(SumVsXoR(n));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's notice that
\$ n + x = n \oplus x \$  is true
when and only when
\$ n + x = n \vee x \$  is true

This is because
\$ n + x \geq  n \vee x = n \oplus x + n \wedge x \$.

Where:

- \$ \vee \$ - bitwise OR
- \$ \wedge \$ - bitwise AND

So we just need to calculate the number of zero bits in the \$n\$.
Let's calculate the nonzero bits:

```
private static int NumberOfSetBits(ulong i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555UL);
    i = (i & 0x3333333333333333UL) + ((i >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333UL);
    return (int)(unchecked(((i + (i >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FUL) * 0x101010101010101UL) >> 56);
}
```

*The method above was copy-pasted from this answer: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709523)*

Then rewrite the `SumVsXoR` method:

```
private static int SumVsXoR(ulong number)
{
    int numberOfBits = (int)Math.Log(number, 2) + 1;
    return 1 << (numberOfBits - NumberOfSetBits(number));
}
```